# how to schedule task in spring scheduler by using calendar object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I am developing a web application based on spring. Requirement is as follows :
**User enters a date (in string format).**
**Schedule a task for that date (only once)**.

My code is:

```
calendar.setTime(formatter.parse(dateFromForm));
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
.
.
String cornExp = "0 "+minutes+" "+hours+" "+day+" "+month+" "+year;
```

i want to pass `cornExp` value to:

```
@Scheduled(cron=**cornExp**)
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Edited to clarify question

Comment: You can't do it with the annotation. With the annotation, you need to supply the cron schedule in your source code. But you only get that information when the user enters it.

Comment: @Andrew Spencer Thanks andrew. can you provide the code or source to do this...please

Comment: There's an example in section 28.3.2 of the Spring docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html but this is what Harden Zhang already gave you

Comment: the Runnable() & run() showing error....

Comment: saying that remove @Override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html)

like this with a spring Bean  &  the code from [springside project](https://github.com/springside/springside4/blob/master/examples/showcase/src/main/java/org/springside/examples/showcase/demos/schedule/SpringCronJob.java):

```
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;
@PostConstruct
public void start() {
    .
    .
    calendar.setTime(formatter.parse(dateFromForm));
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    .
    .
    final String cornExp = "0 "+minutes+" "+hours+" "+day+" "+month+" "+year;

    threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("SpringCronJob");
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

    threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(new Runable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //run task
            //...
        }
    }
         , new CronTrigger(cornExp));
}

@PreDestroy
public void stop() {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = threadPoolTaskScheduler.getScheduledExecutor();
    scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: can you provide full code.because, i am new to spring & you are not using Schedule annotation

Comment: Runnable() & run() showing errors... saying that Runnable() -- change to java.lang & run()-- remove @Override annotation

Comment: my code from [springside](https://github.com/springside/springside4/blob/master/examples/showcase/src/main/java/org/springside/examples/showcase/demos/schedule/SpringCronJob.java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/57119-quartz-cronexpression-from-database) for step by step guide

Basically, you need a `CronTrigger` object and then need to set `trigger.setCronExpression` from database programmatically.